# Spring 3.x failed to load applicationContext

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4, applicationcontext

I am trying to run a simple junit test on my Spring 3.x MVC project and having trouble doing so due to a test error stating how it fails to load the ApplicationContext which I do not need for this particular unit test.

I am testing a simple Controller that mocks a HTTP request that adds a user to the system but it fails.

Here is my test controller class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/test/resources/controller-context-config.xml" })
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserController controller;


    private String jsonUser = "{ \"Username\":\"jonneymendoza\",\"EmailAddress\":\"jon@google.com\", \"Password\":\"12345678\",\"FirstName\":\"jono\", \"Surname\":\"richy\", \"Country\":\"united kingdom\",\"Bio\":\"Bio stuff goes here about the user. where he comes from etc etc. all is well. lets go go go\" }";
@Before
    public void setup() {
        //controller = new UserController();

        assertNotNull(controller);

    }

@Test
    public void testCreateNewAccount() {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = controller
                .createNewAccount(new HttpEntity<String>(jsonUser));
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());

    }


}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String>createNewAccount(HttpEntity<String>request) {

        try {

            userService.registerNewUser( JSONObject.fromObject(request.getBody()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (InvalidDataException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }


         return new ResponseEntity<String>(null, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

`controller-context-config.xml` file located in src/test/resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define controllers here for testing -->

    <bean id="UserController" class="com.jr.freedom.controllers.Controller"></bean>





</beans>
```

Output of error using command line `mvn install -x`:

```
Tests in error:
  testLogin(com.xx.controllers.ControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testCreateNewAccount(com.xx.controllers.ControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  testGetUserProfile(com.xx.controllers.ControllerTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Output from eclipse Junit:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jr.freedom.user.UserService com.jr.freedom.controllers.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.jr.freedom.user.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jr.freedom.user.UserService com.jr.freedom.controllers.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.jr.freedom.user.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.jr.freedom.user.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:952)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:821)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 41 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your unit test, the `UserController` is autowired in, so you will need an application context for that bean will need to be defined somewhere...

Comment: i have created a new xml content that defines that bean and still get the same issue

Comment: Possibly try classpath:controller-context-config.xml for the config location.

Comment: Yes i did try that as well before trying file:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not require an Application Context then remove the following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Then in the `setUp` create your object under test and wire it manually with your mocks, e.g.:

```
controller = new UserController();
controller.setUserService(mockUserService);
... etc...
```

If you do need an Application Context then one of the ways you can load it is by adding the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. For an `xml` configuration it may look like the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/controller-context-config.xml")
public class ControllerTest {
...
```

Comment: Im trying this in maven using mvn install -X and that contextConfig does not work either. i will try running it from eclipse

Comment: Added output from junit eclipse. interesting as it shows a fileNotFound error dispite the file being inside src/test/resources

Comment: @jonney Oh, I think I made a mistake, try `@ContextConfiguration("/controller-context-config.xml")` instead.

Comment: No matching bean of type UserController :( so it seems to at least find the context but it cant find my controller class! is it because i have two packages of the same name? i have com.jr.freedom.controllers on both the test and main folder

Comment: @jonney Re: packages - that shouldn't be a problem. If the error is coming from the wiring of the field `ControllerTest.controller`, try renaming it the field to `userController`. It might be worth asking this as a new question if that doesn't resolve it.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct as it has fixed the initial issue of not loading a context file properly thanks

Comment: @jonney No problem, glad I could help in someway.